# What is Teamviewer VPN's protocol?

Tags: vpn, teamviewer

I am having a hard time figuring out what protocol does Teamviewer VPN use. Is it IPSec transport mode or tunnel mode? Or is it something else?

I was not able to find any documentation related to this..

Comment: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) can probably get you all the info you could ever want on the protocols used, and then some.  If you're okay doing some manual testing.